# Running a different application with variable arguments in Qt

Tags: qt

I am  developing GUI for a project using Qt and I need to browse for a file and open it in an editor.I have written the code to browse the file but I don't know how to open the same filename on geany. It would be great if somebody would help me out with this.

```
#include "check.h"
#include "ui_check.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QProcess>

check::check(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent),
 ui(new Ui::check)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

check::~check()
{ 
    delete ui;
}

void check::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "/home",      tr("Files (*.*)"));
    ui->filePath->setText(fileName);
    QProcess *OpenFile = new QProcess(this);
    OpenFile->start("geany fileName"); //but this opens a file by name fileName.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best is to use the start(QString executable, QStringList arguments) overload, because it gets the quoting of spaces in executables and arguements right. In your case, that would be

```
OpenFile->start("geany", QStringList() << fileName);
```

Comment: @user2376807: If your question is answered, you should "accept" the answer.